# UNIX Socket: Can a client ever read data meant for another client?

Tags: sockets, network-programming, unix-socket

Consider a server process being contacted by multiple client processes using UNIX socket as the IPC mechanism.

Each client code runs in infinite loop trying to read and write data from/to the socket.

My question: How does a client know that it is not reading data meant to be read by some other process? The server process is writing data to a single socket, right?

For TCP/IP this question doesn't make sense - a socket would mean a tuple `<remote host, remote port, local host, local port, protocol>` so processes running off different machines trying to access the server can never read each other's data.

But for UNIX sockets it's just a file right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Could you add some code?

Comment: @tafoo85: This is just a generic case of a UNIX server process being contacted by multiple client processes. Since the IPC scheme is a UNIX domain socket which maps to a file, my question is how does a client know if some data is for it since the server is always writing the data to the same socket?

Comment: It usually helps with explanation if I can reference some code.  That's all.

Comment: 'The server process is writing data to a single socket, right?': wrong. It is writing to a different accepted socket in each case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- At the server each client has it's own socket. Clearly you won't read data that was sent to a different client.
- a UNIX socket is *not* a file, but a lot of its functionality can be accessed through file API calls.

Comment: +1. Can you please share some link where I can find how the server interprets UNIX sockets or anything that discusses about the internals in some detail.

Comment: The old unix adagium is: "everything is a file". Not all files are the same (you can't seek() a tty, for instance), but open() read() write() are implemented on most files/inodes. Listen() and bind() are implemented for socket-descriptors, but not for disk files, obviously.

Comment: I think I said the same thing. It *looks like* a file. But it isn't.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the comment was not targeted @yi_H, but at the OP.